# UI Muliselect widget issue

Tags: jquery, user-interface, filter, multi-select

I'm having a problem with the UI Multiselect widget, which i'm using to filter a series of product photos.  It works fine when only one box in the widget is selected, however, when multiple boxes are selected it displays results for the entire catalog as opposed to just the selected categories.  I think perhaps I'm joining the array of checked boxes incorrectly. I've coded a series of these multiselect widgets with different product attributes.  After the user selects from each they submit by clicking a separate button which then filters the results.  Here's a sample of my code.  Thanks for the help.

```
$('button.submitFilters').click(function() {
    //FILTER VALUES:
    var genreVal = $('#filterGenre').multiselect("getChecked").map(function()  {
        return this.value;
        }).get().join();
```

then, to filter the results:

```
$('.main article[class*=' + genreVal + '][class*=' + sizeVal + '][class*=' + orientVal + '][class*=' + subjVal + '][class*=' + artistVal + ']').show();
```